# What probability to assign to each classification?

Tags: classification

Given the following data:

```
Features: {20, 10, 10}, Classification: "One"
Features: {10, 20, 10}, Classification: "Two"
Features: {10, 20, 30}, Classification: "Two"
```

And the question arises to which classification belongs:

```
{10, 10, 20}
```

Is the correct answer:

```
One     0.33
Two     0.33
Unknown 0.33
```

Or the correct answer is:

```
One     0.25
Two     0.5
Unknown 0.25
```

Or maybe there is another correct answer?

Comment: What kind of model are you running? Most models explicitly calculate predictions on a continuum that can be interpreted as a probability before those scores are binned into discrete classifications by some kind of `predict` method.

Comment: I'm not running a model, I'm developing a classification algorithm, and I'm asking a fundamental question, what is the correct probability that the data should get?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to answer this question, because it is similar to asking "what is the next number in the sequence 1,2,5,10...?" There is no correct way to extrapolate to new data without some assumption (i.e. a model) that relates the data's features to the desired outcome, and a metric by which you fit that model to past data. Otherwise, your past data gives you no information that would help you assign classification probabilities to new points.